# Inject dependency for a class using dagger hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger, dagger-hilt

- I am trying to implement `dagger-hilt` in my Android app. Right now I have four classes in my app but I am confused while creating a dependency for it.

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**:

```
class MainActivityViewModel(
    var musicPlaybackConnection: MusicPlaybackConnection
) : ViewModel() {

    fun hello() {
        Log.d("TAG", "${musicPlaybackConnection.isConnected.value}")
    }
}
```

**MusicPlaybackConnection.kt**

```
class MusicPlaybackConnection(
        private val context: Context,
        serviceComponentName: ComponentName
    ) {
        var isConnected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { postValue(false) }
 

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: MusicPlaybackConnection? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context, serviceComponentName: ComponentName) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: MusicPlaybackConnection(context, serviceComponentName)
                    .also { instance = it }
        }
   }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(view)

       mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
         this, MainActivityModelFactory(
            MusicPlaybackConnection.getInstance(
                this,
                ComponentName(this, MyService::class.java)
            )
         )
       ).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

        mainActivityViewModel.hello()
    }
}
```

**MyService.kt**

```
class MyService: MediaBrowserServiceCompat(){}
```

- I want to inject `MainActivityViewModel` class using dagger-hilt inside `MainActivity`.
- **Note:** Currently in the above code I have instantiated `MainActivityViewModel` inside `MainActivity`, but I want to do same using **dagger-hilt**.

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependencies and following the basic guide? https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
@ViewModelInject is way old, so use code below to inject viewModel.

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor( private val _playbackConnection: MusicPlaybackConnection) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

First why you want to inject viewModel in main activity?

Best way to initialize viewModel in activity or fragment is:

```
private val mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
```

with using  `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:X.Y.Z"` dependency

But anyway if you want to inject viewmodel

you should first provide the **viewModel** to provide viewmodel at least you need to have lifecycle owner, it can be activity or fragment

if you need to inject **MusicPlaybackConnection** inside **MainActivityViewModel**

You need to provide **MusicPlaybackConnection**

```
@ActivityScoped
@Provides
fun provideMusicPlaybackConnection(
                       @ActivityContext context: Context,
                       serviceComponentName: ComponentName): MusicPlaybackConnection =
    MusicPlaybackConnection(context, serviceComponentName)
```

and then in **MainActivityViewModel** class

```
 class MainActivityViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val _playbackConnection: MusicPlaybackConnection) : ViewModel() {
          ...
    }
```

Hope My answer will help you.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit this part `@ActivityContext context: Context`, is this `MainActivity ` that context is referred to?
I believe this is old version of Hilt (maybe 2.28?). I tried this way on 2.37, and it failed :(. 
Not sure how to use this ActivityContext, and make sure it refer to a specify activity, in this case is `MainActivity`

Comment: ActivityContext is actually activity as context of in which component installed module,

. If the binding that you wanted to retrieve were in the ActivityComponent, you would instead use the ActivityContext.